# Display something in specific day with PHP

Tags: php, unix, time, specifications

Ive got a some products on my site which are going to be importat for people in some specific day, lets say some products are perfect to display on valentine's Day, some of them at First of April and many products in many other days. 
So my question is:
**How i can let a site display some specific products in specific days?**

I think there should be a way that i can use UNIX TIME in my DB and every day just load script which check current UNIX TIME with UNIX TIME in DB but its a bit complicated (unix time is in second and i just need specific days not hours or seconds) so i wonder if there is some easier way how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code as no specifics given...

First create some array/object representing your promotions:

```
 $promos = Array(Array('product_id' => 566,
                  'date' => '12-04'),
            Array('product_id' => 565,
                  'date' => '16-07'),
            Array('product_id' => 565,
                  'date' => '23-07'),
            Array('product_id' => 565,
                  'date' => '22-07'),
           );
```

then check the current date and query accordingly:

```
 // get todays date
$today = date('d-m');

// put items to be displayed today in $display_today
$display_today = Array();
foreach($promos as $promo){
    if($promo['date'] == $today) array_push($display_today, $promo);
}

// display somehow
foreach($display_today as $promo){
    // query products by id and display
}
```

1. you don't have to deal with database timestamps unless you want to store promotions in database as well.
2. In practice that kind of functionality should be extended to cover date spans as typically valentines day promition would last a few days before VD ect.

Comment: I just noticed i need to compare dates and it will be pretty hard with this so i use UNIX TIME, if somebody need it , here is example code:

echo strtotime("now"), "<br />";    //unix time now
echo strtotime("21.06.2013"), "<br />";      //unix time specific day
echo date("d.m.Y",1371765600);             //convert unix time on date

Comment: just bear in mind that you have to be careful comparing dates from potentially different sources with strtotime as the way it works can be described as 'the best attempt at parsing string as date considering timezone=>locale settings in php.ini'. Bottom line - watch out as it might suprise you in an ugly way